# Is it possible to install Ubuntu Server without booting into the installer?

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation

I have a home server that I plan to boot off a USB drive (NOT a live USB, but rather a permanent install to the USB drive). The usual procedure for creating a USB drive with a permanent install on it is this: you use two USB drives. One is a live USB that you boot into, which you then use to install the OS to the other as if it were a normal drive.

Is it possible to skip the middleman and create the permanent install directly? Can I run the installer as a CLI application from within an existing installation, instead of from within the live USB environment?

This might be an XY problem, in which case I'd appreciate any pointers to a better solution! My use case for this is that I'd like to automate my setup as much as possible. Ideally I'd have a script that creates a full installation on a drive without any manual intervention.

Comment: Have you heard of [Automated Server Installation](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall)? Would this serve your needs?

Comment: @mpboden that's going to be my fallback option if I can't figure out something better. But the problem with it is that you still create a live USB drive. I could probably figure out how to have it automatically install to _another_ USB drive, but this seems error-prone (how do I make sure it doesn't accidentally format my internal drives?) Just feels like directly installing to a USB drive is cleaner, faster, and safer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can, because there is **a *compressed image* of Ubuntu Server that is portable like the iso files**. You need no iso file, no installer, only extract and clone from the compressed image to the drive where you want it, an internal drive, an external drive or maybe a virtual drive in a virtual machine.

I would recommend the [jammy image that corresponds to version 22.04.x LTS](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/jammy/daily-preinstalled/current/).

See also the thread about the preinstalled image at the Ubuntu Forums, [Ubuntu Server amd64 compressed image (when extracted) boots in UEFI and BIOS mode](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692) . Please read the whole thread before you start extracting and cloning to your computer.

Comment: Sick, thanks! Seems like this + Ansible should be able do exactly what I was looking for. Just to make sure: this image is a stable version, right? (asking mostly because it's called "daily", and some discussion in the linked thread)

Comment: Jammy alias 22.04.x, the stable LTS version is still receiving updates/upgrades. After the installation and testing, you might want to remove the proposed repository in order to get only well tested upgrades.