# How to install ubuntu, on a completely different SSD, without touching windows bootloader?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-10

I have Windows 10, lap, with 8gb ram disk, and **a extra ssd slot**, I also have **an extra 256gb ssd**...with 50gb of personal files in it.

**1 >**Is it possible to install, in a same ssd as with windows in it, by making a new partition for Ubuntu, without making any changes to Windows Bootloader?...
till now, I had searched about installing ubuntu in same ssd with windows in it, came to know that, it makes some changes in Windows Bootloader partition..

**2 >**So, Im thinking of installing Ubuntu in extra 256gb ssd... will that also, make some changes to Windows-Bootloader?... in the primary ssd, also theres one problem, I have  about 50gb of personal files in that 256 gb ssd, Im thinking of, using diskmanagement and make a new 100gb partition in that 256gb SSD, and install Ubuntu in it, Will that work fine?..will ubuntu erase the whole drive.. or just use the partition created for it.. please tell me, how do I go about - installing ubuntu in 100gb partition of the extra ssd, without erasing my 50gb personal files......

**3 >**also have some some doubts about ubuntu filesystem, does ubuntu install using ext4 filesystem, can we change it to use ntfs?...after install, will the ubuntu file explorer, also show-n-read the, files from another ssd with windows in it... Or, in another case, will the Windows file explorer show-n-read the, files from extra ssd, with ubuntu install partition in it....

Comment: Just as you have to use Microsoft formats like NTFS for Windows, you have to use Linux formats for Ubuntu. But Ubuntu can read/write to NTFS if you have Windows fast startup off. If installing Ubuntu 22.04 that uses Ubiquity, see this bug on second drive installs. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Some suggest removing Windows drive, Another is https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator Partition in advance with ESP and an ext4 partition and use Something else install option. Do not use auto option

Comment: [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1491334/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-server-without-booting-into-the-installer/1491338#1491338) and links from it may be helpful for you to install Ubuntu in a separate [external] SSD. It does not involve any classic installer, you simply extract from a compressed image file and then clone the extracted file to the target SSD. It will use the whole drive. In that link I recommend the jammy (22.04.x LTS) version, but if you have a new computer and run it in UEFI mode with secure boot you may need a newer version, 23.10, in order to make it boot.

Answer (score -1):

1. Usually it's better to install Ubuntu *after* windows, which means replacing windows' bootloader with grub and using it to boot windows.
2. It will, but there're some ways of forcing not to install a linux bootloader.
3. NTFS support of not that great in linux and I would encourage you not to try it. ext4 is great and you should probably stick to it.

If you just want to try Ubuntu (that's what I'm gathering from these questions) then maybe.. install it in a virtual env?